# Shopify Trying to create a script tag in shopify but returns an error

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, guzzle

I am trying to build an app in shopify, so uing their API,
[as shown here](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag#create)
But while I am requesting a POST request on that URL i.e.

```
https://demo-store.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json
```

It is returning an error with HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request)

```
{"errors":{"script_tag":"expected String to be a Hash"}}
```

Sample code

```
$access_token   = "my-access-token";
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
try {
 $response = $client->request($type, $url,[
    'headers'   => ['X-Shopify-Access-Token' => $access_token],                    
    'form_params' => ['script_tag'=> \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(["event" => "onload", "src" => "https://app.dev/app.js"])],
    ]);
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    var_dump($response, $result);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex);
    }
```

Comment: You don't include any code, so no one can help you with this vague question.

Comment: before doing -1 just ask if you need any but as the question stats that I am already requesting a POST request to that URI so, I am testing with postman

Comment: @DavidLazar , Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When making POST or PUT requests to Shopify's API you will usually want a `Content-Type: application/json` header. Version 6 of Guzzle [has a `json` option that adds the header automatically.](https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=request#json)

Here's an example of what that could look like when creating a script tag:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$script_tag = [
    'script_tag' => [
        'src' => 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/js-buy-sdk/v0/latest/shopify-buy.umd.polyfilled.min.js', 
        'event' => 'onload'
        ]
];
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://45345345345.myshopify.com/admin/script_tags.json', [
    'json'    => $script_tag,
    'headers' => ['X-Shopify-Access-Token' => $access_token]
]);
```